# Open filters in pop-up

Tags: views, javascript, modal-dialogs

I have a **search field** in my view and also some **other filters** like filtering between 2 dates or filtering between 2 prices.

Now I have something like this:

[image]

When I click on `Uitgebreid zoeken ...` the div pops open like this:

[image]

Now I would like to replace the div that pops open when you click on the link with a pop-up. The pop-up should contain all the filters and the apply button.

But I don't now how to start with this. What would be the best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A custom Views template for the exposed form might do it.

wrap it in a div, and use either a custom jQuery or third party pop-up script within the tpl.

Comment: What do you mean with the custom Views template?

Comment: You can customize the layout (theme) of views just like anything else. If done correctly, you should be able theme the exposed filter as a pop-up. (https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!theme.inc/group/views_templates/7)

Comment: @nielsv Hi were you able to achieve using filters as popup ? If yes I would like to know how implemented it successfully.
If you see the link http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/selectmenu-custom/#popupDemo and "Multiple, icon left, long list:" on that page. I need to implement it in a views exposed filter which is taxonomy term reference field